# How to move a WordPress website from local to remote without over-writing database?

Tags: database, wordpress, localhost, local, transfer

I have an online website built with wordpress and already started, with articles and media.
I am working locally on the site I would like to replace it with, but by moving this local site to the hosting space (in remote), I would not want to delete articles and media from the old site.
Is it possible in your opinion? How?
Thanks

Comment: You can't simply "merge" two websites. I suggest you import the necessary articles from the remove website to your local development website and then completely overwrite the remote one with your local site. If there are not many articles you can do that manually. Otherwise you can use plugins such as WP All Export / WP All Import to mass import data between WP installations.

Comment: @OzgurSar thank you. In your opinion, is there a way I could do the same thing with MySQL or Phhmyadmin?

Comment: Valeria, do you mean to import your existing articles from the remote site to the local site?

Comment: Yes! I mean that

Comment: You can use phpmyadmin when you move your local wordpress database over to the remote server, but not for individual posts. Instead you can use the Wordpress' built-in tool for that. Check this article. https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/import-export-wordpress-website